# What is a difference between two sentences?

Tags: tense, progressive-aspect

There are two sentences below.

> 1) She couldn't stand **being kept waiting**.
>
> 2) She couldn't stand **keeping waiting**.

Please, let me know about difference.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means that someone was making her wait, and that she couldn't bear waiting longer; she wanted to take action to avoid waiting longer.

The second sentence is not correct usage.   An English speaker would understand it to mean "She couldn't stand waiting any longer" - which is like the first, only it does not necessarily involve another person or situation forcing her to wait.  But it sounds like incorrect English.   Use the first instead, or "couldn't stand waiting any longer."